Keeping original color with color ramp alpha
When using a color ramp and adding transparency to remove the checkers from a png image and make the background see through, the original color gets removed. Pressing + and adding "new color stops" I can never get the color to match exactly. How can I make the background see through while keeping the original color intact?

It would help to see this image. Color Ramp input is a factor (one number), if you plug a color, I think it will use the Value (luminance) of the color. Assuming you are talking about material and not compositing : there isn't a keying node like in compositing. The solution probably depends on the image you are working with.

I edited my post and added a picture. the image on the left is the original, the right is the one i'm working with. As you can see, i got the background transparent but the colors don't exactly match the original no matter how many +'s you add. what kind of node do i need to get the colors from the original image to match the new one?

Your issue is that you are trying to map the luminance to a gradient of color, you won't get any similar result like that. Could you also upload your image ? So that we can try to do it.

I uploaded the picture on my first post for you to take a look at.
